# jQuery autocomplete not displaying data returned from Ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Below an Ajax call wrapped inside a jQuery autocomplete `source` function. checking the return value in Fiddler and also in Chrome's Network console, I can see that the data is being returned to the view and in the correct format.

However, the normal list of items that occur when the user starts typing do not appear. You can type as fast/slow for as little/long as you want and nothing will appear.

I've set a breakpoint in the controller method (this is an ASP MVC site) just to make sure that part of the program was functioning properly, and it fires every time.

I'm only a few weeks new to jQuery so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(function () {
    $('#DRMCompanyId').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("compSearch", "AgentTransmission")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: request,
                success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        response($.map(function (value, key) {
                            alert(value);
                        return {
                            label: value,
                            value: key
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

EDIT

I added a couple `alerts` to the code. The `alert(data)` will fire but the `alert(value)` will not.

Here is a copy of the returned `json` from the Chrome's debugging console

[image]

And here is the controller method that returns the key/value pair in the form of a `Dictionary` object.

```
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");

            Dictionary<string, string> companies = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (XmlNode childNode in parentNode)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(childNode["content"].InnerText))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string name = childNode["title"].InnerText;
                        string id = childNode["content"].InnerText.Substring(0, 6);

                        companies.Add(id, name);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }

            return Json(companies, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            results = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }

        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: can you show your json?

Comment: You mean the returned values or where it is set in the controller?

Comment: i mean returned json..

Comment: Just added a screen shot to the post.

Comment: Is your response from server (data) an array? also $.map function expects the array as first argument to make the projection.

Comment: No, it's not an array it's a C# `Dictionary` object. I'll add part of the controller method to the post.

Comment: Try changing "$.map(function (value, key) {" to "$.map(data, function (value, key) {", it should work according to your code.

Comment: Thank you!! You should write this as an answer and I'll accept it. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @NealR added as answer :)

Comment: `$.map` does **not** expect an array, it works with either an object or an array. It's right there in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $.map function expects an array/object to enumerate on, as first argument. ref [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

try changing

```
$.map(function (value, key) {
```

to

```
$.map(data, function (value, key) {
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/ says that the `$.map` function expects two parameters; the first being an array.  I think that you need to use the `$.each` method instead.

I also believe that in this context, `response` is a callback function that you are supposed to invoke with the data from AJAX as the parameter, as in `response(data)`.

Shooting from the hip here, I think that your success handler should look about like this:

```
            success: function (data) {
                    var x, array = [];
                    for(x in data) {
                        array.push({
                            label: data[x].value,
                            value: data[x].key       
                        };
                    }
                    response(data);
             }
```